# merge feature branch into the develop with SmartGit

Tags: git, smartgit

I accidentally made a feature branch in SmartGit.

I wish to merge it back into the develop branch and delete it - I am new to
SmartGit, so I am unsure as how to do this without making a mistake.

I usually use the git-flow feature that does this automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the git-flow feature from within SmartGit:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- be sure, all pending things pushed & pulled, feature branch is rebased (so nothing newer on master)
- switch to develop branch
- open log view, right-click on tip of feature branch: Rebase to (HEAD) ... (the 2nd option)
- ➪ your develop commited get stacked on top of what's already on develop
- push (no force push needed)